# Check user has permission to view page

Tags: permissions, liferay, liferay-6

I want to check if particular logged in user has rights to view page? I tried **hasPermission** of permissionchecker but no luck.

can anybody help me out?

Thanks !!!

Comment: can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

In your controller create this function,  I wonder why they've not included a similar function through some Liferay Util function

```java
public boolean hasUserPermissionForAction(String actionKey){

    // where actionKey can be "VIEW", "UPDATE" etc

    long groupId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();

    String name = PortalUtil.getPortletId(request);
    String primKey = themeDisplay.getLayout().getPlid() + LiferayPortletSession.LAYOUT_SEPARATOR + name;

    return themeDisplay.getPermissionChecker().hasPermission(groupId, name, primKey, actionKey);
}
```

For your case, call it using `"VIEW"` as the `actionKey` parameter.